# How fast can our skin recuperate from sunlight?

Tags: human-biology, cell-biology, skin

Imagine that you get burned in the sun after half an hour. But a quarter and another quarter is also a half hour. So if you go into the sun 15 minutes and after one hour another 15 minutes do you get equally burned? Or what in case you pause half an hour etc. Is there a kind of schedule for recuperation times/pauses?

Comment: It depends a lot on skin type. Pale skin has higher sensitivity to sunlight and is burnt relatively more easily than dark skin.